# Generar secuencias de números basado en una condición en R (Busco alternativas a mi solución)

Tags: base-de-datos, r, condiciones

En primer lugar, pongo un dput de mi base de datos:

```
dput(study)
    structure(list(state = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Control", 
    "WV"), class = "factor"), yearqtr = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
    5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 
    19L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 
    14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L), .Label = c("2001, 2", "2001, 3", 
    "2001, 4", "2002, 1", "2002, 2", "2002, 3", "2002, 4", "2003, 1", 
    "2003, 2", "2003, 3", "2003, 4", "2004, 1", "2004, 2", "2004, 3", 
    "2004, 4", "2005, 1", "2005, 2", "2005, 3", "2005, 4"), class = "factor"), 
        market_share = c(0.52714, 0.49988, 0.49205, 0.49713, 0.49724, 
        0.49729, 0.49972, 0.50085, 0.46391, 0.4343, 0.42327, 0.41887, 
        0.38585, 0.36963, 0.3565, 0.33753, 0.31054, 0.30456, 0.28855, 
        0.48893, 0.47956, 0.47722, 0.48834, 0.47811, 0.47284, 0.47466, 
        0.47867, 0.47851, 0.48252, 0.49165, 0.49599, 0.48444, 0.47741, 
        0.47537, 0.46563, 0.45466, 0.45886, 0.45484), groups = c(1, 
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), time = c(1, 
        2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 
        19, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 
        17, 18, 19)), row.names = c(NA, 38L), class = "data.frame")
```

Genero una secuencia de números de 1:n() para la variable time según lo establecido en `group_by`

```
study <- mutate(study, groups=ifelse(state=="WV", 1,0)) %>% 
    group_by(groups) %>%     
    mutate(time= 1:n())
```

Mi pregunta es sencilla: ¿Es posible crear la variable `time` sin necesidad de pasar primero por `group_by`?

Intentaba algo como

```
 study <- mutate(study, groups=ifelse(state=="WV", 1,0)) %>% 
time=ifelse(groups==1, 1:n(), 1:n()))
```

pero sólo obtengo una secuencia de 1:38 y no dos de 1:19

Si es necesario utilizar `group_by` primero, no tengo problema, sólo deseo saber si es posible crear la variable directamente desde el primer llamado a `mutate`.

Agradezco cualquier comentario o sugerencia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usando puramente `dplyr`, no creo que puedas evitar el uso del `group_by()` lo que sí puedes evitar es crear una nueva columna (`groups`) innecesariamente y el uso del `ifelse()` ya que justamente con `group_by()` no lo necesitamos:

```
study %>%
        group_by(state) %>%
        mutate(time = row_number())
```

En este caso, como `mutate()` actúa sobre los grupos definidos en el `group_by()` podemos crear  la variable `time` con el número de fila relativa a cada grupo.

También, mediante una solución netamente en R base y siempre que los grupos estén ordenados como es al menos tu ejemplo, podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```
study$time <- sequence(rle(as.character(study$state))$lengths)
```

Con `rle()` obtenemos un vector con las longitudes de cada grupo y con `sequence()` generamos las secuencias para cada grupo.

Comment: Muchas gracias, como siempre. ¡Saludos!